# Has someone ever used Selenium RC with Firefox Portable (specifically FF3.6)?

Tags: selenium

I'm having difficulty to make them work together. How do you setup the server or the test to use Firefox Portable?

One of the things I had to do was specify the exact location of the Firefox.exe. No problem there, but it seems the server has problems with launching the firefox profile from the portable location.

The browser gets loaded, but stops there - the test steps themselves do not get performed.

Comment: . you really need to add a lot more information if you want us to be able to help with this.

Comment: I really can not figure out any thing from this question :-/

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that some of the changes in Firefox portable were made in the profile handling code. Selenium not only instantiates the browser, but it also creates a basic profile and installs the WebDriver plugin in that profile among other things. I'm guessing here, but if you're not specifying the location of the profile, Selenium is probably creating it in the same place it would create it for an installed version of Firefox. I would try manually specifying a profile (which has the WebDriver add-on installed manually first) that corresponds to the local directory that portable Firefox uses.

Comment: I'm still learning on RC, haven't yet migrated to WebDriver. Soon, though!

Answer (score 1):

How are you even using portable FF with Selenium RC?

In RC, I believe Selenium looks for the (default) FF install location for where to invoke the FF binary. I'm assuming you are talking about setting (*nix/Windows/Mac) environment variable or Windows registry setting that points to FF binary (creating it if not exist, which it likely would not exist for FF portable since no install occurred)?

For RC, you specify Firefox binary when you specify the browser string, and instead of '*firefox' it would be like '*firefox C:\pathTo\firefox.exe' and similarly for Linux/Mac, '*firefox /pathTo/firefox-bin', where for Mac it looks more like '*firefox /pathTo/Firefox.app/morePaths/firefox-bin'

If you were able to use and specify FF binary with RC, then did you try specifying absolute path to FF profile to load with? That might work?

Like:

java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\PathTo\FFProfileDirectory"

I was able to run automation specifying path to portable FF but on Mac. Just recently trying for Windows, not sure if I can get it to work. Haven't tried for WebDriver yet.

Comment: One can also try to run with FF portable w/o specifyinga profile to see if that works as well.